# Pass VueJS data key-variable to onmouseover atrribute inside a <a> tag

Tags: html, vue.js

I have the following bits:

```
<script>
window.onload = function vue () {
      var app = new Vue({
                  el: '#app',
                  data () {
                      return {
                      message: 'Click here to edit your details!'
                  }
                }
              });
    }
</script>
<h2>Hello <a id="myName" href="#" onmouseover="???" v-bind:title="message">{{username}}</a></h2>
```

({{username}} is being fetched from a Django view.)

What I need is to pass the 'message' value to **onmouseover** somehow, *or something similar*, so that when you hover over the username link, it shows the value of message in a Vue tooltip.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered that the VueJs data variable containing the "message" needs to be **v-bind** to an actual HTML element, as is, for example, an html tag's **'title'** attribute. Thus, it can be passed to 's title attribute likewise:

```
 <div id="app">
       <a id="user_name" href="#" v-bind:title="message">{{user_name}}</a>
 </div>
```

And having only this:

```
var app = new Vue({
                      el: '#app',
                      data: {
                          message: 'LOL'
                      }
                    })
```

And that's pretty much how it works, without a need for a mouseover call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use v-on mouseover to fire a function wich will set the message :

```js
window.onload = function vue () {
          var app = new Vue({
                      el: '#app',
                      data () {
                          return {
                          message: '',
                          username: 'sss'
                      }
                    },
                    methods: {
                        showMessage() {
                            this.message= 'Click here to edit your details!'
                        }
                    }
                  });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>Hello <a id="myName" href="#" v-on:mouseover="showMessage" v-bind:title="message">{{username}}</a></h2>
    <div>
        {{message}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue, and also I realised that the <a> row has to be inside the div specified in this case #app ! Otherwise, while it was out of this <div> it didn't work.